# What makes a really good marrow bone?

Tags: beef, marrow

Every now and again I really crave some crustinis with marrow.  I've had mixed success trying to find the ones where the marrow can easily come out.  There's usually sinewy ossificans and it makes it hard to get all the marrow out easily.

What are some reasons that some bones don't have ossified material inside and some that do?  Does it happen as the animals get older?

Comment: The two follow up questions might be better asked on Biology.

Answer (score 1):

Some butchers will custom cut beef leg bones. You can specify a short cut for the marrow bone so that your retrieval device can fully reach all of your marrow. I work at a charcuterie and we frequently cut marrow bones to order.

Answer (score 1):

Leg bones, the femur esp, as said have most readily available marrow, and some butchers will slice these in half rather than cross section to make scooping out marrow easy. Whether you have much marrow or more actual bone matrix can depend on how close to the end of that bone you're getting. But pretty typically get a femur and you're rocking.

If you think about yourself and imagine where the longest hollow tubes are, you'd probably guess the legs, upper leg then lower, then arms and ribs, and then you're moving to brain for more similar.

Does that help?
Also pressure cooking can be a really nice, fast way to loosen the marrow from the bone.
V healthy stuff there.